# liquibase maven plugin multiple changeLogFile

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, liquibase

I'm using `liquibase maven plugin` to update the database changes via `jenkins` automated builds.

I have this in my `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <changeLogFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema.sql</changeLogFile>
        <changeLogFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/data.sql</changeLogFile>
        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:postgresql://${db.url}</url>
        <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I need to run `schema.sql` before `data.sql`. When I run this locally it works. When I run it via jenkins the `schema changeLogFile` executes second, so in order to make it work I reversed the commads.

**Question**: What's the order of execution? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: why do you need to reverse the order of execution? I guess you first need the schema, then the data. Are you getting any error on Jenkins?

Comment: Sorry about that, what I wrote was misleading. I've updated my question. Basically when I run it via jenkins the data.sql executes before schema.sql which should not be the case

Comment: which goal of the liquibase-maven-plugin are you invoking from command line? what's the full maven command you are executing?

Comment: `mvn liquibase:update -Ddb.url=IP:PORT/DB -Dliquibase.username=USERNAME  `

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [official goal documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/generated/update-mojo.html#changeLogFile) specify that only one entry is foreseen:

> **changeLogFile**:
>   Specifies the change log file to use for Liquibase.
>
> - **Type**: `java.lang.String`
> - **Required**: No
> - **Expression**: `${liquibase.changeLogFile}`

You can add further entries, but they will be ignored and maven will not complain: it doesn't validate plugin configuration' content, it cannot, because that part is up to the plugin and not known upfront by maven. That is, is generic.

To ensure a deterministic order and have two `changeLogFile` executed, you should specify several plugin `executions` as following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <changeLogFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema.sql</changeLogFile>
        <changeLogFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/data.sql</changeLogFile>
        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:postgresql://${db.url}</url>
        <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>update-schema</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>update</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema.sql</changeLogFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>update-data</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>update</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/data.sql</changeLogFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note: we are specifying a common configuration for all executions outside of the `executions` section, then per each `execution` we are only defining the additional configuration, which is every time the different file.

The deterministic order is guaranteed by Maven: for the same plugin, for the same phase, the order of declaration in the POM will be respected.

However, this executions will be part of your build now as part of the `process-resources` phase, which is probably not what you want. So in this case, better to move it to a profile as following:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>liquibase-executions</id>
        <build>
            <defaultGoal>process-resources</defaultGoal>
            <plugins>
                <!-- MOVE HERE liquibase plugin configuration and executions -->
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And then execute the following (according also to your comment):

```
mvn -Pliquibase-executions -Ddb.url=IP:PORT/DB -Dliquibase.username=USERNAME
```

Comment: The xml schema allows it though. Isn't that an indication that it is allowed? More importantly, not only that but the steps are executed as expected (apart from the order that is, in jenkins)

Comment: Yes your answer certainly provides a way of achieving the desired effect. Upvoted, but I'll wait a little longer in case an answer that provides insight as to why this is happening. If no such answer comes along I will accept this one. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: this [old forum entry](http://liquibase-user.narkive.com/Auc0yPtF/running-multiple-changelog-file-via-maven-plugin) also supports the fact that only one entry is supported

Comment: The documentation doesn't help, as it is mentioning the input about the tag. The thing is, I'm using multiple tags. But the old forum solves this. It seems you are right, but still, it works how can this be? Anyway I've accepted your answer and acknowledge that the documentation is vague for this particular case.

Comment: Looking [at the mojo code](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/liquibase/maven/plugins/AbstractLiquibaseChangeLogMojo.java) through its hierarchy, the changeLogFile is indeed handled as a single file

Comment: Can you provide the full solution with the profile? I get 'profiles.profile[liquibase-migrate].plugins.plugin[org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin].executions.execution.id' must be unique but found duplicate execution with id default @ line 461, column 40

Comment: ouch, my bad, sorry, just updated the answer adding id elements in each execution with different value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106740/discussion-between-alkis-and-a-di-matteo).

Comment: Similar issue here :
Step 1 : purge-data
Step 2 : anonymize-data
Only step 2 is executed
Maven is 3.6.3 with liquibase 4.2.2